# View JBoss realtime log with GWT

Tags: gwt, log4j, jboss7.x

I was wondering if there are any tool out there for viewing the JBOSS (7.1.1 or higher) log file in realtime with a GWT widget?  I'm looking for something that will tap into the log4j events on the server side and pipe these to a srolling window in a browser.

Are there any tools like this?

Thanks

Comment: You can use https://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/ for push server side update to GWT client.

Comment: Just to note, JBoss AS 7.x does not use log4j.